# boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() assertion

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using `boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` 
and sometimes get:

> Boost::Chrono - Internal Error.

my application is multi threaded so does any one know if the `now()` function is thread safe?

I looked at the implementation of the `now()` function and it uses a `static` variable which might mean that it is not thread safe.

My code looks like this:

```
auto algTimer = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

the message i get points to:

C:\boost\boost_1_48_0\boost\chrono\detail\inlined\win\chrono.hpp line 44

Comment: Can you post the code that errors?

Comment: This is also an assertion that must include a file & line number. Then it should be easy to track down the reason, say, by looking at the code — http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/chrono/detail/inlined/posix/process_cpu_clocks.hpp

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is some sort of re-entrant issue?  I have the same error with Boost 1.55 on Windows, and each time I have checked the assertion occurred in two threads at the same time.

Unfortunately, sometimes the QueryPerformanceCounter call fails at line 42 of boost\chrono\detail\inlined\win\chrono.hpp, which causes the assertion error.

```
if ( (nanosecs_per_tic <= 0.0L) ||
        (!boost::detail::winapi::QueryPerformanceCounter( &pcount )) )
{
  BOOST_ASSERT(0 && "Boost::Chrono - Internal Error");
  return steady_clock::time_point();
}
```

There is a Boost ticket for this error, but not much activity.  https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8006

I verified that the arguments to QueryPerformanceCounter are QWord-aligned, as [required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so that is not the problem.

I have two suggestions for addressing this problem.  The first suggestion is to use the [other overload](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.system_clocks_hpp.steady_clock) for `now`, which accepts a system::error_code and does not assert.  The second suggestion is to either disable asserts, or provide Boost with an assert handler via BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER...see [assert.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/assert.html).